# Multiple Telegraf Daemons trying to write to same DB in InfluxDB

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-output-plugins

I have two telegraf daemons running.

Daemon 1 : Input = kafka topic : sample_topic, Output = InfluxDb : DB = telegraf, MEASUREMENT = KI1
Daemon 2 : Input = kafka topic : sample_topic2, Output = InfluxDb : DB = telegraf, MEASUREMENT = KI2

The two daemons read different kafka topics and writes to two different measurements in InfluxDB database "telegraf"

What I observe is that both the measurements KI1 and KI2 are not created simultaneously. Only one measurement is created. When I kill the daemon which has already created the measurement, then the other measurement gets created in the db by the other daemon.

Is simultaneous writes to different measurement allowed in InfluxDb?

I even tried the same by writing to two different InfluxDb databases, telegraf and telegraf2. I observed the same behavior.

Also, is it possible to do all this using only one daemon? Where in I have multiple input plugins to read different kafka topics and different output plugins to write where ever required.

Daemon 1 :

```
[tags]
    topic = "sample_topic"


# OUTPUTS
[outputs]
[outputs.influxdb]
    # The full HTTP endpoint URL for your InfluxDB instance
    url = "http://localhost:8086" # EDIT THIS LINE
    # The target database for metrics. This database must already exist
    database = "telegraf" # required.
    skip_database_creation = true
    database_tag = "KI1"

#INPUTS
# Read metrics from Kafka topic(s)
[[inputs.kafka_consumer_legacy]]

    name_override = "KI1"
    ## topic(s) to consume
    topics = ["sample_topic"]
    ## an array of Zookeeper connection strings
    zookeeper_peers = ["localhost:2181"]
    ## Zookeeper Chroot
    zookeeper_chroot = ""
    ## the name of the consumer group
    consumer_group = "sample"
    ## Offset (must be either "oldest" or "newest")
    offset = "oldest"
    ## Data format to consume.
    ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
    ## more about them here:
    ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
    data_format = "value"
    data_type = "string"
    ## Maximum length of a message to consume, in bytes (default 0/unlimited);
    ## larger messages are dropped
    max_message_len = 65536
```

Daemon 2 :

```
[tags]
    topic = "sample_topic2"

# OUTPUTS
[outputs]
[outputs.influxdb]
    # The full HTTP endpoint URL for your InfluxDB instance
    url = "http://localhost:8086" # EDIT THIS LINE
    # The target database for metrics. This database must already exist
    database = "telegraf" # required.
    skip_database_creation = true
    database_tag = "KI2"


#INPUTS
# Read metrics from Kafka topic(s)
[[inputs.kafka_consumer_legacy]]

    name_override = "KI2"
    ## topic(s) to consume
    topics = ["sample_topic2"]
    ## an array of Zookeeper connection strings
    zookeeper_peers = ["localhost:2181"]
    ## Zookeeper Chroot
    zookeeper_chroot = ""
    ## the name of the consumer group
    consumer_group = "sample"
    ## Offset (must be either "oldest" or "newest")
    offset = "oldest"
    ## Data format to consume.
    ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
    ## more about them here:
    ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
    data_format = "value"
    data_type = "string"
    ## Maximum length of a message to consume, in bytes (default 0/unlimited);
    ## larger messages are dropped
    max_message_len = 65536
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I observe is that both the measurements KI1 and KI2 are not
>   created simultaneously. Only one measurement is created. When I kill
>   the daemon which has already created the measurement, then the other
>   measurement gets created in the db by the other daemon.

I don't know how did you verify it. But chances are rare for such an anomaly.

> Is simultaneous writes to different measurement allowed in InfluxDb?

Yes.

Comment: I ran both the daemons and I am publishing data to both the topics. I expected the write to happen simultaneously. But only one measurement got created and the other did not. When I killed one daemon (the one which had already written the data into Influxdb), the other measurement got created. 

I figured out why it's happening. This is cause of the legacy plugin. With the legacy plugin, both the daemons are trying to connect to zookeeper at the same time.

Connected to [::1]:2181 is what both the daemons have. So until one daemon is killed, the other does not get connected to zookeeper.

Comment: This issue is not seen with the new kafka consumer plugin. So I switched over to the new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use different consumer groups in each Telegraf instance

instance 1

```
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
...
consumer_group = "sample-1"
...
```

instance 2

```
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
...
consumer_group = "sample-2"
...
```

So in the case of using the same consumer_group for both instances, that means both instances are in the same group. Only one instance in each group is allowed to consume the data. If one instance is down, another instance in the same group will take the responsibility in consuming the data from Kafka topics.

It would be late to answer, but it should be the solution for the same problem.